# Center map between two points WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, bing-maps, windows-phone-8.1

im trying to center the windows phone map between two points, adjusting center and zoom to make that points visible at the same time.

Im Android and IOS there are functions to do it, as example this is how to do it in Android:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(myPos.getPosition());
builder.include(defaultPos.getPosition());
mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 50));
```

How can i do the same in WinRT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting Windows Phone 8.1 instead of WinRT (Windows 8/8.1) then you can do the following:

```
var geoboundingBox = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeoboundingBox(
new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 40, Longitude = -90 }, 
new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 45, Longitude = -100 });
map.TrySetViewAsync(new Geopoint(geoboundingBox.Center));
```

Comment: I need to do it on Universal APP, both Phone and PC

Comment: Ok. First off there is no Universal map control for WP/WinRT. However it is possible to use Bing Maps in Universal apps. I wrote a blog post on how to do this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2014/06/24/using-maps-in-universal-apps.aspx

Comment: You will need both pieces of code I provided to do what your looking to do in a Universal app.

Comment: I know, it looks really easy similar to android or ios, but i cant find the classes needed for Phone (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps) i can only find it on PC (Bing.Maps).

Comment: Make sure its a universal app you are creating. Universal apps are for Windows Phone 8.1 and above. You will only find the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps namespace in the WP8.1 app. If you look at the blog post I provided in an earlier comment it shows you how to access this namespace in a universal app using conditional compilation symbols.

Comment: Also, you can switch the target of the code using the drop downs at the top of the file. It's likely set to Windows Store app, switch it to Windows Phone and the namespace should appear resolved.

Comment: Working on Phone, please note its Geopoint not GeoPoint VS will not resolve it.

Comment: Yup, you are correct about Geopoint. Force of habit to camel case words when I type.

Answer (score 0):

For the Bing Maps WinRT control you can do this in two different ways. The first is to create a LocationRect from the two points. This will create a bounding box for your locations. You can either set the map view to this LocationRect using the SetView method on the map which will center and zoom to these locations, or you can use the Center property of this LocationRect to set the view of the map such that it is centered on these two locations, without zooming into the map. Something like this should work:

```
var bounds = new LocationRect(new Location(40,-90), new Location(45,-100));
map.SetView(bounds.Center);
```

Another method requires a bit more calculation but a good option to know if you come across other map controls that don't have an easy solution like the first one I mentioned. This method consists of calculating the center coordinate between the two locations. I have a blog post on how to do this from a vey old version of Bing Maps here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/calculating-the-midpoint-of-a-line-segment/ The logic can be easily migrated to other programming languages.

It sounds like you are new to developing with Bing Maps in WinRT. I recommend checking out my free ebook on how to create location intelligent Windows Store apps. It goes into a lot of detail on how to create great apps using the Bing Maps control. You can download a copy of it here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/

Comment: That are classes for the bing maps [AJAX!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427621.aspx) control, i see LocationRectangle for Silverlight but im using WinRT API, any idea?

Comment: LocationRect is part of the Bing Maps SDK for WinRT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846491.aspx

Comment: That is the Bing.Maps namespace (PC), but on Phone i need to use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps and i cant see that classes or any similars.