# Adjust zoom level to fit box Bing maps WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, bing-maps

Now that im able to center the map between two points [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422894/center-map-between-two-points-winrt), i need to adjust the zoom level to the box.

My code looks like this:

```
private void centerMap(Geoposition pos, MapPoi pos2)
    {
        try { 
    #if WINDOWS_APP
            //TODO PC Maps
    #elif WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        GeoboundingBox geoboundingBox = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeoboundingBox(
        new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = pos.Coordinate.Latitude , Longitude = pos.Coordinate.Longitude },
        new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = pos2.lat, Longitude = pos2.lng });
        map1._map.TrySetViewAsync(new Geopoint(geoboundingBox.Center),geoboundingBox.MaxAltitude);
    #endif
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    }
```

It seems to be working fine, but it doesnt change the zoom level, so i need to adjust it to fit the box exactly on the maps camera.

How can i get the zoom level needed to fit the box, so both corners are visible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to also zoom then use the TrySetViewBoundsAsync method on the map: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn637065.aspx